# Android: programmatically capture audio from a specific channel?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I would like to capture the audio from a specific channel (eg. I have a 3.5mm headset and a Bluetooth headset both connected to an android phone. Right now, it receives audio from both sources when I use "AudioSource.MIC" and I would like to capture an audio from a bluetooth headset only) is there anyway I can specify the audio channel programatically ?
How can I programmatically capture audio from a specific channel on Android?

My device is the Nexus One, running Android 2.3.7, Bluetooth headset Jabra BT 2035

Comment: Please share your research for the others. That will help to others.